# Invalid literal for int()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning python and I am trying to code a calculator that compares prices of butter, calculates percentage differences, and which one has the lowest price for 100 grams.

```
def procenta(x,y):
 vysledek = (y-x)/x * 100            # (b-a) : a * 100
 return round(vysledek, 2)
tesco = float(input("Zadejte cenu masla v Tescu: "))
tesco_g = int(input("Zadejte gramaz v Tescu: "))
lidl = float(input("Zadejte cenu masla v Lidlu: "))
lidl_g = int(input("Zadejte gramaz v Lidlu: "))
kaufland = float(input("Zadejte cenu masla v Kauflandu: "))
kaufland_g = int(input("Zadejte gramaz v Kauflandu: "))

cena_tesco = int(tesco)/(tesco_g[:2]/10)
cena_lidl = int(lidl)/(lidl_g[:2]/10)
cena_kaufland = int(kaufland)/(kaufland_g[:2]/10)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "python", line 6, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Don´t worry about what does the other text means, it's my native language, can translate it eventually. However, if I change it to:

`cena_tesco = float(tesco/(tesco_g[:2]/10))`

I get `TypeError float object is not subscriptable`.

Comment: Your first error shows you that you passed an empty string into `int()`. The second error shows you that `tesco_g` is already a float object.

Comment: But how should i fix this ? Sorry , I am beginner. I need idiot-proof answers.

Comment: What is it you are trying to do with `cena_tesco = int(tesco)/(tesco_g[:2]/10)`?

Comment: Its calculating price of butter per 100 grams. For ex. If we have 300 grams for $21 , it´s supposed to take first two digits from tesco_g ; 30 and divide them by 10. 21/3. That gives us $7 for 100g of butter.

Comment: Why not just do `cena_tesco = tesco/tesco_g * 100.0`?

Comment: You just simplified the code alot. I feel abit stupid. I will try if it give me error. Man , you are legend. Thx , solved.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `tesco_g` to be an integer by casting it with your 5th line.  Your TypeError is telling you that the `varname[:2]` syntax doesn't work because your type doesn't have indices.  To reframe what the interpreter is doing:
1. It reads `tesco_g[:2]`
2. It checks: does the type of `tesco_g` have a method for indexing up to the second element?
3. It doesn't find that method, and throws an error.

What is the `cena_tesco` line supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

If I will get it to work , it will be printed :

```
print("Tesco is the cheapest shop with price of",*cena_tesco*,"for 100 grams of butter.")
```

Its supposed to calculate price of butter for 100g.
What should I do with tesco_g[:2] so it take first two digits from tesco_g and use them to calculate the price ?